# How to unit test a vue script setup component?

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vue-composition-api, vitest, vue-script-setup

We want to use vue composition api using the script setup in our company. How would one write unit tests for a script setup component?

We're using Vue 2.7.14 and vitest if that matters.

Comment: Isn’t it possible to use Vue Test Utils? There is some information about the @vue/test-utils in the [vue 2.7 announcement](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-2-7-naruto.html)

Comment: >Note: if you are using @vue/test-utils, you will need to keep vue-template-compiler in the dependencies because test utils rely on some APIs only exposed in this package.